# Ubuntu touch work with the nexus 9?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I recently bought a nexus 9 running android lollipop.  I wanted to either dual boot or install Ubuntu touch on it, and I noticed that most nexus devices were working. However the website hasn't been updated for the new nexus 6 or 9.  Is it possible to install Ubuntu touch on a nexus 9?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to install Ubuntu touch on a nexus 9?

Sorry, but currently it is not possible.